QGIS 3.34: field with expression not editable
In a current project I have a LineString Layer (called 'Test') with two fields "MDB" and "ML" which have a default value expression that automatically fills in true/false and predetermined text depending on the content of the third field "Typ".

The widget of "Typ" is a classification whereas the "MDB" is boolean and "ML" is text edit.
The default value expression for the field "MDB" is
CASE
    WHEN "Typ" = 'SOS' THEN true
    WHEN "Typ" = 'UWA' THEN true
    WHEN "Typ" = 'VUG' THEN true
    ELSE false
END

The default value expression for the field "ML" is
CASE
    WHEN "Typ" = 'SOS' THEN 'SOS_01'
    WHEN "Typ" = 'UWA' THEN 'UWA_01'
END

In the layer properties both fields are checked as "Editable".
The problem that occurs is that after creating a feature, however, the field is not editabel. For example, I can´t switch the field "MDB" from true to false or change the content of the field "ML".


You're forcing the application of the default value on update - naturally any edit would be reverted back to that default value, hence the field appears uneditable.

But otherwise the field "ML" wouldn´t update / the expression wouldn´t apply. Or is there another posibility?

When should the expression be applied?`

The expression should be applied whenever I select a value from the field "Typ" (i.e. SOS. Depending on this value the expression in the fields "MDB" and "ML" should be filled in automatically but it needs to stay editable because I want to make manual changes for certain cases.

So, you want to apply the default value upon feature creation?

Yes! So if I select 'UWA' (in the field "Typ") for example, the boolean in "MDB" should switch to true. At the same time I want to maintain the option to change true into false after I finished creating the feature.

I am unsure whether default values based upon other values work without the checkbox "apply on update" - but have you tried that?

I have tried in the past and it worked with checkboxes and text edit. After updating to the new LTR it seemed to have changed. Maybe it´s a bug or it was intended to work like this?
